# Retrieving the current page on template, Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

At the moment im using:

```
$route=$app->getRequest()->get('_route');
```

Based on my routing.yml:

```
done_punctis_brand_stats:
    pattern: /brand/{id}/stats/{type}
    defaults: {_controller: DonePunctisBundle:Brand:stats, type: 'general'}
    requirements:
        _method: GET
        id: \d+ #digit [0-9]
```

So with this in mind, route will echo: **done_punctis_brand_stats**

The problem is if the user is on /brand/1/stats/general or /brand/1/stats/othervalue the output will be always  **done_punctis_brand_stats**, how can I know the difference (on a php template)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
$app->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
```

Comment: +1, you also might want to check the api documentation [here](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) where you can find a lot of interesting things about the Request object of SF2.

Answer (score 1):

It's `{{ app.request.requesturi }}` in twig so `$route=$app->getRequest()->getRequestUri();` in your PHP template.